# Puzzling birthday match probability

Tags: probability

OK I've been searching the Web for an answer to a burning question. And finally this page has.. Or almost had an answer!

In a group of 19 people.

What are the odds that....

2 specific pairs of people share the same birthday.

A and B on 1st of Jan C and D on 1st of Feb

AND no one else has a same birthday with anyone else in the group of 19 people...

Lastly. Not sure if this is relevant...

What are the odds that..

Mom has same birthday as daughter in law 1 And dad has same birthday as daughter in law 2.

Or does this not matter in math... As in who's who?

Been trying all sorts of methods but I can't seem to figure out what the odds are.

Like would it be one in a million orrr?

Thanks in advance math whizzes!

Comment: Perhaps you can demonstrate some of those `Been trying all sorts of methods` so that people can help more effectively. When adding information, please click on the tiny "edit" instead of commenting.

Comment: More like one in 194,491

Comment: Thanks! Problem is I'm not even sure how to approach it, I read up about the birthday paradox where odds of same birthday is 0.27%.. Then I stumbled upon this question on this site which was trying to solve exactly this! Let me find the link and share it here..

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1539271/probability-of-exactly-two-pairs-share-a-birthday-and-each-pair-shares-differen

Comment: Now in that page there was an answer...... Like this...

Comment: There was an answer to that question just saying to divide by 2 to avoid to problem of double counting....

Comment: So I'm really quite lost as to how would I solve this if I wanted to know the odds of a specific 2 pairs of people out of a group of 19 people who had the same birthdays... 2 on date A and 2 on date B. With no one else in the 19 havining same birthdays.

Comment: A very simple point that will help you think like a mathematician:  It makes absolutely no difference whatsoever that the two randomly chosen people happen to have a relationship such as daughter-in-law.  The odds are the same as if you consider a man and his third wife's sister's hair-dresser's son's scout master's second cousin's rowing partner.  Think mathematically:  these are person A and person B.  Done.

Comment: Hint: you may split your question into 3 parts: 1) what is the probability of $A$ and $B$ having their birthday on 1/Jan; 2) what is the probability of $C$ and $D$ having their birthday on 1/Feb; and 3) what is the probability of the remaining 15 having different birthdays. Note that the daughters-in-law formulation is different because it does not specify the dates.

Comment: Hmmm thanks guys! Let me have a ponder and see if I can calculate it...

Comment: how'd it go? were you able to solve